# Where is CHART DATA in this Excel template?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have downloaded an Excel template for family budget but cannot find where the chart is getting the data from. It says 'CHART DATA' as if there is a sheet with that name but it is not.

You can find the template [here](https://templates.office.com/en-US/Family-Budget-TM10000094). Where is this data?

I feel so ashamed asking this question here because I've been using Excel for many years and can code good macros in VBA but this is upsetting me. Could you also tell me a good Excel book or course? I think I have to make a big refresh.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is in a hidden sheet called "CHART DATA"

Steps to unhide it:

1. Click Home > Format.
2. The Cells group on the Home tab
3. Under Visibility, click Hide & Unhide, and then click Unhide Sheet.
4. In the Unhide box, double-click the name of the hidden sheet that you want to display.

Check this link for further reference:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/hide-or-show-worksheets-or-workbooks-a8f5977c-8f1a-4ce7-a45d-58cd2c7516de#bmdisplayhiddenworksheet

Regarding the Excel books, it depends on your needs, but have a look at this list:
https://trumpexcel.com/excel-books/

Answer (score 0):

Right click any of the Sheet Tabs.
Select "Unhide..."
Select "CHART DATA" and click "OK."